# Automater.py install

Tags: tar

Getting this message when unzipping file for `automater.py` any ideas ?

```
tar -xvcf master.tar.gz
tar: You may not specify more than one '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or  '--test-label' option
```

Answer (score 2):

`-c` is for **C**reating a tape archive.

`-x` is to e**X**tract a tape archive.

Both are mutually exclusive.  Since you are extracting the archive you should not be using `-c`.